# How to re-construct an image with just the horizontal co-efficient of wavelet transform?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I am trying to reconstruct the input image with just the horizontal coefficients of the stationary wavelet transform.

```
[A,H,V,D ] = swt2(x,1,'sym4');

A = 0; V = 0; D = 0; %i am setting other co-efficents to zero since i am only intersted in the values of H %

Y = iswt2(A,H,V,D,'sym4') ; %this gives the following error below%
```

> Error in `iswt2/reconsLOC` (line 153)
>   
> `ca(sR,sC)`,`ch(sR,sC,k)`,`cv(sR,sC,k)`,`cd(sR,sC,k)`, ... 
>   
> Error in `iswt2` (line 122) `a = reconsLOC(a,h,v,d);`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've omitted the top line of your error message, which gives a clue what the problem is:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

The problem is that you can't just set a matrix to a scalar `0`, you have to set *the entire matrix* to zeroes, so that it still has the same size as `H`. This will work:

```
A(:) = 0;  % Fills every element of A with zero
V(:) = 0;
D(:) = 0;
Y = iswt2(A, H, V, D, 'sym4');
```